# mount specific entry in fstab

Tags: bash, fstab, cifs

I have a script that creates an `fstab` entry. However I want to test it before rebooting.

It is in `cifs` format and works on reboot but I cannot test it with the mount command. I have tried;

`sudo mount <FILEPATH>`

I get;
`mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

But that doesn't work?
I cannot use `sudo mount -a` as it throws errors for already mounted devices...any ideas?

Comment: unmount the conflicts then run `sudo mount -a` ?

Comment: What error do you encountering when trying to mount the drive? They are similar but you could also try umount /path/ as well

Comment: problem is the fstab entry has `\040` to escape spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount the moint point:

```
sudo mount /path/to/mount_point && echo OK || echo ERR
```

Comment: `mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Comment: so, you tested it ... the test worked, but was not successful. Note: `/path/to/mount_point` must exist and must be empty.

Comment: It works from the fstab at boot, but not via cli to test

Answer (score 0):

Having run;
`sudo mount --verbose <FILEPATH>`

I discovered that, of course, it's trying to mount as `root` due to the `sudo` command. As the mount is using `krb5` to mount it needs the `user` credentials NOT `root`

So I fixed it with;

`sudo -u "$USERNAME" mount "$DFS_MOUNT"`